# Get pixel color from window of running app - JAVA

Tags: java, colors, window, jmonkeyengine

I am working on application in JAVA using `jMonkeyEngin`e. If app is running, I need get a pixel color at a given coordinates. My app extends `SimpleAplication`. Robot does not work, the app window is smaller than the screen. I did not find something like `getColorBuffer()`, `getColor()`, `getPixel()` or similar function in SDK so is there in `Java` another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this information from the frame buffer.
You can get the result of rendering (the frame buffer containing the result) by adding a `SceneProcessor` via `ViewPort.addProcessor()`.